# Apache Druid Native Query Explain Plan

Tags: sql-execution-plan, druid

I am trying to understand the performance of certain aspects of native queries in Apache Druid. Is there a way to get the execution plan for a native query? For SQL in Druid we have...

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FORM ds
```

is there an equivalent command for native queries?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not (to my knowledge). The `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR` which you describe will actually show you how your SQL syntax is converted to a native druid query.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent command for native Druid queries, you can collect 'query/time', 'query/segment/time' and other query related metrics Druid emitted to analyze the bottleneck of your queries.